# JavaFX Applet web-page refresh and close notifications

Tags: java, html, browser, applet, javafx

How do I detect when user closes(navigates away) or refreshes web page with JavaFX applet in it? I want to do some clean up in my code on those events.

Java Applet had some callback methods to do that, but how would I do it in JavaFX running in browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps:

1. You *may* need to use a Javascript's window.onunload event to tell your JavaFX app to "close". If you do this, you can then
2. Add `FX.addShutdownAction(myfunction);` to your `run()` function. This will execute myfunction when your app is closed.

I don't have some complete code for you here, but I hope it's a start. You *may* not need to do step 1.

Comment: Yes, I did something similar. Added javascript window.onbeforeunload = onClose; into html page and added function onClose() : Void {...} function into loose code portion of the javaFX script.